# What is wrong with this JSON:

Tags: javascript, html, json, script-tag

I've looked at several examples, all over, and in my opinion this is valid, but when I load JSON as a script file, e.g:

```
<script src="../js/side-menu.json"></script>
```

Chrome gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

That is the `:` at the end of `"side-menu":`. This is the JSON:

```
{
  "side-menu": {
    "sections": [
      {
        "dashboard": [
          {
            "title": "Firewall",
            "url": "dashboard_2.html",
            "icon": "icon-bulb",
            "menuVisual": "selected"
          }
        ]}
    ]}
}
```

Is this perhaps because the browser is interpreting the file as JavaScript instead?

Comment: Your JSON is well formated, you can check it on http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Yes. Using a script tag without specifying the lamguage will assume js not json.

Comment: So what are your expectations about `<script src="../js/side-menu.json"></script>`? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Why do you load it as a script ? it should be loaded into some variable as a string , or decoded as a structure, or loaded in rt as an ajax call.

Comment: You should use Json as defining it type="application/json" in script tag.

Comment: @Gar, I need to load JSON from a given local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that your are trying to load pure JSON using the Script tag which is by default looking for plain old script code. You have <del>two</del> one option<del>s</del> here -

1. <del>Specify `type="application/json"` in the script tag, also give it an `id`. Then wherever in you need to access the data, find the script element using its id and do `JSON.parse($("#scriptelementid").html());`. Replace jQuery with plain javascript if you ain't using it.</del>
2. OR, change your json content to this -

   ```
   var exportedData = {
     "side-menu": {
       "sections": [
         {
           "dashboard": [
             {
               "title": "Firewall",
               "url": "dashboard_2.html",
               "icon": "icon-bulb",
               "menuVisual": "selected"
             }
           ]}
       ]}
   };
   ```

Comment: A previous answer implies that option 1 does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515141/html-javascript-how-to-access-json-data-loaded-in-a-script-tag-with-src-set

Comment: There were no answers when I took to writing this one :).

Comment: I meant a previous answer to a pervious question. Sorry about the link above. Wrong link

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point now.

Answer (score 2):

json looks fine for me as well. Check this issue, it seems related

[HTML/Javascript: how to access JSON data loaded in a script tag with src set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515141/html-javascript-how-to-access-json-data-loaded-in-a-script-tag-with-src-set)

Answer (score 1):

The JS parser confuses the curly braces with a code block instead of an object literal. You can avoid this by putting it into parentheses like this ({...}).

Your file won't be JSON anymore if you do this. How exactly this followup problem can be fixed depends, but you'll have to think about something different first: What exactly do you expect from including a file that contains only JSON? After all, this JSON won't be available in a variable if you do that, since there's only the JSON value, no assignment to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you are trying to achieve doing this.

```
<script src="../js/side-menu.json"></script>
```

This is going to get your json and interpret it as javascript.

Maybe what you are looking for is.

```
 <script language="javascript">`
 var my_json = {
  "side-menu": {
    "sections": [
      {
        "dashboard": [
          {
            "title": "Firewall",
            "url": "dashboard_2.html",
            "icon": "icon-bulb",
            "menuVisual": "selected"
          }
        ]}
    ]}
};
</script>
```

inside the `<script>` tag.