# can't get data from external local json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to show an 'alert' box with text from JSON file in it. But it seems like I can't get data from my JSON file. It just doesn't throw an alert box.

```js
var thebook = JSON.parse(book);

function showAlert() {
  alert(thebook[0].word);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="book.json"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="showAlert()">show alert</button>
</body>
```

And an example JSON file

```js
[
  {
    "word" : "cuiller",
    "page" : 23
  },
  
  {
    "word" : "arbre ",
    "page" : 245
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the value of `book` at the top of the code?

Comment: Seems like you try to load json in a wrong way. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515141/html-javascript-how-to-access-json-data-loaded-in-a-script-tag-with-src-set

Answer (score 1):

you need to request the resource from inside your JS code not just reference it
you can do this via a XMLHttpRequest which wiill return the text from the file, you can then parse the text into an object using JSON.parse

An example would look like this

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: How it's suppose to answer OP question ?

Comment: @executable it answer the question exactly as asked,though i admit the language could be clearer

Answer (score 1):

In your `book.json` Have your JSON stored in a variable (like `var book` given below).

```
var book = [
  {
    "word" : "cuiller",
    "page" : 23
  },

  {
    "word" : "arbre ",
    "page" : 245
  }
];
```

Stringify it before parsing/alerting it.

```
thebook = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(book));

function showAlert() {
  alert(thebook[0].word);
}
```

**Working JSFiddle link:** https://jsfiddle.net/h5knqobs/9/

Hope this helps!

Comment: aren't OP want to retrieve json from file?

Comment: @david Thanks for pointing it out.. Corrected my code, Check edited code above

Comment: converting the json file to a js file works but doesn't deem to be in the spirit of what they are trying to do

Comment: I agree with you @MikeT, But it was the requirement of OP, Hence opted that way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you retrieve JSON from file

```
var book = (function() {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': "/book.json",
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
})();
```

After you store the JSON value into a variable, parse it like this.

```
var thebook = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(book));
```

**EDIT**

Here is the better version of my answer

```
var book = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "/test.json",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        book = data;
    }
});
```

In your `showAlert` function, you can simply call `book[0].word`.

Comment: why would you need to convert the js object to json and then parse it back again? just set the book directly with the data object as you have disabled async its not like the promise will not have returned

Comment: the OP said that the OP trying to get data from JSON file, not the JSON directly from JS code.

Comment: i think you miss my point, your success callback has already parsed the json into a js object as your specified a json datatype so where you do `json = data` you are setting json to a js object so `var thebook = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(book));` could be replaced with `var thebook = data`

Comment: Thanks @MikeT for finding more efficient way.