# How to pass/import server-side JSON to a vue app?

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I'm building a webapp that requires a JSON file as data. The person using my app in their website should be able to pass in a JSON file hosted on their server so that my app can read it.

In development, I just used `import mydata from "./mydata.json"`, but this won't work in production. I tried to have a computed property that returns `require (this.publicPath + this.datapath)` (where `this.publicPath` is `process.env.BASE_URL`, but it's not able to find the file (if it's relevant, I'm using vue-cli to build).

The structure of my app is that I have a wrapper `App.vue` and then the main component, `main-component.vue` (so that I can pass a prop containing data to the main component).

What's the best way to do this? I've tried using a `<script>` tag in `index.html`, but apparently that's [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13576588/9327866) with JSON. I don't want to use other libraries like jQuery.

(I'm thinking that I could have the user just import their file with the ES6 syntax by creating a new Vue component/app, but I'm not sure how to do that in pure HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an extension of my comment: what you're looking for is to actually fetch the JSON from your server using an XMLHttpRequest. You can do this in a modern, ES6-manner using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
fetch('/path/to/your/json')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Access the parsed JSON as `data`
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `await` in my created method because I needed to force synchronous behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you can try using a .js file that migh work and you can structure the data the same way as in a .json file, afterall a json is just a js object, also i had this problem while doing the same thing.
DISCLAIMER: you might have to restructure your data to be in an exported variable if that is possible, like so:

export const myObj = {your json}