# Javascript load all the keys in external JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have external JSON at location /data/words.json

```
{
    "sports":       ["golf", "hockey", "football"],
    "animals":      ["giraffe", "snake", "lizard", "puma"],
    "video games":  ["pacman", "asteroids", "super mario brothers", "donkey kong"]
}
```

I need to access this in my javascript function.
I have loaded the file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./data/words.json"></script>
```

How can I print all the keys of given JSON and print it on browser? Note that provided JSON does not have a variable name.

Comment: Are you using pure JavaScript or are you using Node/a Node-based framework?

Comment: I'm using pure JavaScript.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `fetch` it instead...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML/Javascript: how to access JSON data loaded in a script tag with src set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515141/html-javascript-how-to-access-json-data-loaded-in-a-script-tag-with-src-set)

Comment: @esqew Can you provide a code snippet please?

Comment: @esqew - Oh no - that answer (your dup) was from 3 years ago. The easiest solution is for the OP to use and `import` statement in a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: If this is just static data, here is a working example that is similar to Tiramonium's answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jcat6q?file=index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON was never meant to be loaded this way, as you've probably come to find out. Why not just use `fetch` instead ([if your expected execution environment supports it](https://caniuse.com/fetch))?

```
const jsonData = await fetch('./data/words.json').then(res => res.json());
```

Depending on what exactly you have in mind when you say "*print all the keys of given JSON and print it on browser*", you could accomplish that pretty easily:

```
Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(key => console.log(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a native ECMAScript module that loads the JSON into a constant and then manipulates it. No need to import it before the script runs either.

**EDIT:**

Having forgotten my older ways of working with pure JavaScript, just remembered you'll also need a web server running on your local machine to be able to properly load resources, even if they are stored locally.

```
<script type="module">
  import * as words from './data/words.json';

  const wordsObj = JSON.parse(words);
  const wordsKeys = Object.keys(wordsObj);
  const wordsSpan = document.createElement("span");

  for (let i = 0; i < wordsKeys.length; i++) {
    wordsSpan.innerHTML += wordsKeys[i] + "<br>";
  }

  document.getElementByTagName("body").appendChild(span);
</script>
```