# Read json file from localhost with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, localhost

I need to read a `.json` file from my localhost, but it didn't work!

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
[
 {"source":"tw1", 
  "text":"fubar"}, 

 {"source":"tw2", 
  "text":"foo"}
]
```

I set up the localhost with the command: `python -m http.server 8888 &`, which is posted [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) here.

I wrote the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/test.json", function(data){
            document.write(data);

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file.. it may help you

Comment: I agree with @Amberlamps.  Please edit the question and show the error you are getting.

Comment: Sry i get no error, i get nothing, thats one of the problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open your server on port `8888`, then you must request it on that port :

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/test.json", function(data){
```

But beware that the server must set the [correct CORS headers](http://enable-cors.org/) if you want to be able to pass [cross domain restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

A third problem is that your code can't compile : you're missing a `});`. The indentation asymmetry makes it obvious :

```
$(document).ready(
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/test.json", function(data){
        document.write(data);
    }); // <=== was missing
});
```

A fourth problem is that you wan't use `document.write` once the page is loaded. You must write using DOM manipulation methods, like `$(document.body).append($('<pre>'+data+'</pre>'));`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, where is the `});` missing, this is above the `</script>` tag or not?

Comment: @dot I edited. You should try to get used to see symmetry in the code. That's how I spot most obvious errors.

Comment: How can i set the correct **CORS headers**, on this simple server, sry the silly question!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're trying to access the json file in your computer, upload your json file to a online server and access that instead of the one that is one your computer.