# JSON Parse File Path

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm stuck trying to get the correct path to the local file. I have the following directories:

```
Resources ->
   data ->
       file.json
   js ->
     folder ->
        script.js
   html ->
      folder ->
         file1.html
```

I'm executing `script.js` from `file1.html`, with js code:

```
var answers = JSON.parse('../../data/file.json');
alert(answers);
```

But it doesn't work, even alert is not starting.
What is wrong?

Also I've tried this:

```
function readJSON(file) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', file, false);
    request.send(null);
    if (request.status == 200)
        return request.responseText;
};

var temp = readJSON('../../data/file.json');
alert(temp);
```

Alert undefined in this case.

Comment: `Alert undefined for me.`, what was the `status`, did it produce an error in your _console_?

Comment: Finally, `if (request.status == 200)` made issues for me. It gives 0 even if it finds the file.

If i delete it, all is ok. Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Since it is in the directory `data/`, You need to do:

file path is `'../../data/file.json'`

```
$.getJSON('../../data/file.json', function(data) {         
    alert(data);
});
```

Pure JS:

```
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("GET", "../../data/file.json", false);
   request.send(null)
   var my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
   alert (my_JSON_object.result[0]);
```

Comment: I didn't realise you could pass a _URI_ to `JSON.parse` and have it perform a `REQUEST` for you, where is this documented?

Comment: yeah.. edit was on the way.. guess should have answered after the fact

Comment: for your pure js alert is not starting also

Comment: my_JSON_object.result is undefined. You would access the Javascript created from the JSON file through my_JSON_object directly instead.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///.../data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I get this same `XMLHttpRequest` error when developing locally.  Are there any non-network calls to load the local JSON file and parse it for use within client-side JavaScript?

Comment: Did not work for me, but [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23419205/1705829) with the asynchronous check if the json is ready worked. I get without it an `unexpected end of JSON input` error which tells me that the json parse starts but does not finish before the next order starts.

Answer (score 10):

This solution uses an Asynchronous call. It will likely work better than a synchronous solution.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "../../data/file.json", false);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ( request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 ) {
    var my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(my_JSON_object);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good answer. I edited it because it's best when an answer stands alone. Dialogue about other answers is appropriate in comments.

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: @Evorlor Change the false on line 2 to true. Otherwise it's a synchronous operation.

Comment: @Evorlor [here](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method) is a closer link to what you are writing that one should use `async` and not `sync`.

Answer (score 4):

[Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Use something like this

```
$.getJSON("../../data/file.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info in firebug console 
    alert(json);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET","<path_to_file>", false);
request.send(null);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

This code worked for me.

Comment: .. but does not work for me, see my comments to the other posts.

Answer (score 0):

If `Resources` is the root path, best way to access `file.json` would be via `/data/file.json`

Comment: Actually, i make it in titanium webview, so normally resources should be root path.
If i make document.location.pathname and start in browser i will for sure get file:/// ...

Answer (score 0):

My case of working code is:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "<path_to_file>", false);
request.overrideMimeType("application/json");
request.send(null);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(jsonData);
```

Comment: .. but does not work for me, see my comments to the other posts. And .. what is the added value here compared to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16991355/1705829)? Looks like copy-paste. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Even if long time answerd, I here is another that does not need to create a request. I created a lg.js script containing a class and some functions (setLg, de, en, ...)
Each "lg" function (de, en, fr, ...) provides a json object containing the translations.

```
"use strict"
class Lg {
  constructor() { this.tr = this.en(); }
  setLg(l) {
    if l == "de" this.tr = this.de(); 
    if l == "en" this.tr = this.en();
  de() {
   "item": "Artikel",
   "login": "Login"
  }
  en() {
   "item": "Item",
   "login": "login"
  }
 }
 var lg = new Lg(); //global accessable object
```

You can then use it by "lg.tr.item"
You could also create a small function, that checks if the "key" is in the JSON object to have some kind of error checking.

Comment: This example is too far away from the question I think. An example should be used without any effort and here, I need `l` var to work with it. Welcome to SO.