# How do I read a single object from json file in react?

Tags: json, reactjs

I want to return a single json object and read the ip address

```
//This is the object in json file
{"ip":"http://localhost:8080"}
```

For example, I want

```
import urlAddress from './url.json';

const url = //the json value;
console.log(url);
```

Comment: your question is not clear. please elaborate

Comment: This might help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991341/json-parse-file-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

objects.json

```
export default {
  "ip":"127.0.0.1"
}
```

app.js

```
import objects from './objects'
console.log(objects.ip) // output: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: thnx for your quick reply