# Reading a local JSON to HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've been trying for some time to read a local JSON file with pure Javascript (no JQuery). I searched the whole Google and Stackoverflow, but it seems that nothing works in my case. I know the JSON.parse, but how do I read the file in the first place on my Javascript?

```
loadJSON(json){
    var savedJSON = JSON.parse(json);
    alert(savedJSON[0].name);
}
```

The main idea is to have a server website to generate a JSON that has the user's saved information, and now I will read the JSON and generate a HTML with that information to use in a Android app, but I'm struggling at reading the JSON. Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean 'local' as in local to the same website, or 'local' as in your local filesystem? Please make sure you edit the question to include your code, and describe exactly what's wrong with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading local json file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Comment: I'm not using JQuery, as specified in my question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: @sidneyreis okay I had overseen that

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp you can read the local (on the server) text file with an `XMLHttpRequest`

This code will print a JSON array in an HTML table.
Contents of file `file.json`:

```
[[ 50.65, 5.37 , 4358684.11 ], 
 [ 50.68, 5.86 , 1849705.79 ], 
 [ 50.33, 6.84 ,  961107.46 ], 
 [ 50.55, 7.32 , 1587473.93 ]]
```

HTML/Javascript

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "file.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "<table border=1>";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr>";
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          out += "<td>"+arr[i][j]+"</td>";
        }
        out += "</tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("JSONtable").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```