# How do i load my local json file just using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, serialization

My json file looks like this

```
{
    "Persons": {
        "Name" : "e",
        "Name2": "e",
        "Id": "4700"
    }, [...]
}
```

How does my code looks like to parse/load this local json file into a html file.
I tried everything out but none of them worked.

Comment: You need to make an AJAX GET request to load data. Then you would use `JSON.parse` to parse text loaded content into object data.

Comment: What are you using to retrieve the data? An attempt should help everyone out.

Comment: @dfsq AJAX GET of the local file will fails in [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787).

Comment: @lexicore it should work if running a local webserver.

Comment: @lexicore: Yes, that is called a "cross-domain request". Only `http://localhost` will work for local AJAX in Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading local json file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Comment: @brbcoding I'd argue that "load a resource using a local webserver" is not the same as "load a local file".

Comment: @dfsq Basis for assumption?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl No, that is not called "cross-domain request". It is called "a special security setting in Chrome", read the link I've posted. Has nothing to do with cross-domain. Can be disabled with `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Comment: @lexicore guess I don't understand cross-origin then. Seems like that post discusses `--disable-web-security` which is [clearly used to bypass cross-domain restrictions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc&q=disable-web-security&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=273)

Comment: @brbcoding If I have a local file `index.html` and a local file `test.xml` directly next to it then trying to load `test.xml` per XHR from a script in `index.html` fails in Chrome. This is the same location, so neither technically nor spec-ally "cross-origin". It is the very very same origin.  So it has nothig to do with cross-origin, no matter what the source code says. It is just some random security feature in Chrome. Hit me hard ~3 years ago, still angry.

Comment: This technically isn't a duplicate of the post @brbcoding linked to.  That question involves jQuery, and this one does not.

Comment: @SeanKendle well, this one doesn't show any code whatsoever so there was no way to know. The other one wasn't tagged as jQuery either (the OP mentioned it, but there are some non-jQuery answers there as well).

Comment: The one you linked to has jQuery in the example provided.  `var json = $.getJSON("test.json");`

Comment: Call me pedantic, but this is a purely javascript question.  If the OP didn't have jQuery, or even know what it was, he would have been confused by jQuery answers.  I just think people too quickly reflexively try to vote down, and call out questions as duplicates on this site.  There should be a little more attempt to help, rather than just can a question immediately.  My opinion.

Comment: @SeanKendle I automatically reach for the close button when there is 0 effort displayed. This is a perfect example of that. If the OP tried "everything" they should at least show some of that attempt. My opinion as well.

Comment: That's a respectable policy, however it's clear this is a brand new user, and that kind of treatment would turn a person away from the site.  I err on the side of helping them understand the rules, rather than simply vote down, or close the question, or mark as duplicate.  The beauty of this community is the willingness to help each other.  I understand your policy, though.  It's hard to help someone who doesn't help us help them!  ^_^

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example from (http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
    // Success!
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

Your `data` variable will then have accessible members like this:

`alert(data.Persons.Name);`

Comment: Depends where the file is in relation to the file you're working on.  If it's in the "data" folder then yes.  As a pointer for further help in the future, definitely include more details, like the location of the data.json file, and some of the code you've tried to use.