# How to load a local file in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have I file named `dump.json` of the form:

```
[{"key": "XYZ", "values": [[1424642400000, 28], [1424728800000, 80], [1424815200000, 92]]}]
```

and, what I would like to do is loading it somehow in JavaScript under the variable name `histcatexplong`:

```
var histcatexplong = [{"key": "XYZ", "values": [[1424642400000, 28], [1424728800000, 80], [1424815200000, 92]]}];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Using Ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Use [`filereader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) in combination with file input. This will also work without running local webserver.

Comment: Also, you may have meant `json` instead of `jason` ;)

Comment: Use [`XMLHTTPRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7346563/3493420

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, this can be used online and offline (doesn't require a webserver) while *XMLHTTPRequest* does. Note that Filereader is only supported in modern browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

```js
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
       var contents = e.target.result;
       document.querySelector("div").innerHTML=  "Got the file.n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
              + "starts with: " + contents
           //store it as JSON
           histcatexplong = JSON.parse(contents);
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<div></div>
```

As an example of what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply send a GET request with no parameters to the `.json` file. Note the following code sample will not work in IE5/IE6 look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) for a more cross-browser solution and must be ran on a server (e.g. localhost) because of [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). A rough idea:

```
 var histcatexplong;
 var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "dump.json", true);
 xhReq.send(null);
 xhReq.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (xhReq.readyState==4 && xhReq.status==200)
      histcatexplong=JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
 }
```

Comment: I like this one but it doesn't work on my Chrome. Can you  double check this answer please?

Comment: It should work so long as you run it on localhost or a server (it doesn't work if you run it as a file because of  [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`, as if the internet connection disconnects midway, it can hang some browsers. However, I don't see why in particular this code shouldn't work.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Fair enough, I will change the third parameter to true.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.... FYI, both files are in the same folder. I could also call either of them through localhost... Any ideas?

Comment: @Guy3000, with `true` (or asynchronous), you need to add a readystate or onload event!

Comment: @Mouser: Oops, thanks for pointing that out. For user 706838, what is the exact error you are getting? I tested it with the code above and it works (after the changes).