# Unable to assign JSON value to variable in HTML

Tags: css, json, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a JSON file with variable in it . But I am unable to assign the value to variable from JSON.

My HTML file is :--

```
<div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
 <div class="huge">
    <p id="demo"></p>
 </div>
 <div>Total</div>
</div>
```

My Javascript is :--

```
<script>
      var text = 'http://localhost:8080/SampleGUI/total.txt';
      var obj = JSON.parse('text');
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.total; 

</script>
```

And my JSON is :--

```
  {
     "text": {
      "total":"19838"
  }
```

}

I keep getting invalid character error for my HTML variable assignment .

Can you please help me with same ?

Regards.

Comment: You are not parsing the text into your JSON.parse.... please check

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21446426/1170430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your trying to get the file you may want to use XMLHttpRequest to retrieve so something like this could do **"untested:**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8080/SampleGUI/total.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log("response",xmlhttp.responseText);
        var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.text.total; 
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

If your using jquery something like this

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/SampleGUI/total.txt", function(data) {

    $("#demo").text = data.text.total; 
});
```

I have attached a jsfiddle of working http://jsfiddle.net/nk0ynou1/

Comment: Where are we defining the variable obj in jquery . Should it be defined as the global variable ?

Comment: Thanks Luke. I don't get error anymore . But the HTML is still not displaying the value for demo . It comes blank.

Comment: whats the exact contents of your json file? To make sure you are receiving  the correct data i would add console.log("response",xmlhttp.responseText); so you can see what is been parsed by JSON.parse

Comment: My exact JSON content is  {
  "text": {
          "total":"19838"
          }
} and I am trying to store the value in variable demo so that I can get it printed within html.

Comment: Here i have uploaded a jsfiddler version of it working http://jsfiddle.net/lukesUbuntu/nk0ynou1/3/

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.text.total;
```

Comment: Page load is failing at var obj = JSON.parse('text');

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
var obj = JSON.parse('text');
```

you are parsing the string `"text"` which is not valid JSON.

For example:

```
$ node
> JSON.parse("text")
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Maybe you meant to parse the JSON string inside the variable named `text`, so remove the quotes.

This should set you in the right direction:

```
$ node
> var text = '{ "text": { "total": "19838" } }'
undefined
> JSON.parse(text).text.total
'19838'
```

Comment: I tried to look at various options. But since I am new to HTML and JSON , I was unable to fix it .

Comment: I tried that but it still fails  with same error .                                                                                    var text = 'http://localhost:8080/SampleGUI/total.txt';
var obj = JSON.parse(text).text.total;                                                                                           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.text.total;

Comment: @RayToal Sure, he should not be doing `JSON.parse("text")`. But the more fundamental problem is that even if he changes this to `JSON.parse(text)`, `text` will not be the desired object from the server because he doesn't know how AJAX works.