# Django - How to use a static file in an other static file

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to refer to a static file in an other static file but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have a javascript file that I include into the html page this way: `{% static 'myJavascript.js' %}`

Then, in `myJavascript.js` I need to refer an other static file (a `.json` file ) but it wont works when I use `{% static 'myJson.json' %}`.

Any one have an idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files are static, which means they are not interpreted by Django, so cannot use tags in them.

However, you can refer to a static file from any other static file using relative paths assuming that the file is accessible.

There are a lot of topics on SO referring to how to include one javascript file from another one, for example: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: In my case, I have a .json to include in a javascript and not two javascripts

Comment: Then try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal absolute/relative path to refer to files inside `*.js` files.

Static files are only **served**, not rendered by Django, therefore you can't use template tags inside of them.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `relative path` please? Because i tried to call the `.json` file using `./myJson.json` (cause the .js and the .json are in the same path) and it won't work

Comment: I don't know your directory structure, are both files on the same directory level?

Comment: Then just use `myJson.json`

Comment: How exactly are you trying to include your JSON file? Can you provide some code?

Comment: I am using d3.js, there is a function called `d3.json()` that take a json file that contains nodes and links to draw a directed graph: `d3.json("myJson", function(error, graph){//draw the graph} `

Comment: Looks like you forgot the extension. Try `d3.json("myJson.json", ...`

Comment: No, I wrote myJson in the comment to explain what I am trying to do, but the extension is well written in my code