# Java rest service with JSON file

Tags: java, json, rest

I have done a project with a simple Java Rest service and Ajax calls.

Unfortanely if i set the path to the json file as something general (fileName.json), it will not open my file.

If i set a complete path like C:\Users\Username\workspace\RestApplication\fileName.json, it works but when i will submit the project for review, it wont have the same path on my teachers computer.

The file currently resides in the main folder of the project. How can i make a general path that will work on whatever computer opens the project?

Thanks!

Comment: may be try jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put the file you want to load in the `classpath`.

> The class path is the path that the Java runtime environment searches for classes and other resource files.

Put your file inside your `src` or `resources` folder (I don't know your project structure)

and try to load it with:

```
InputStream is = TestResource.class.getResourceAsStream("/fileName.json");
```

or put the file under `WEB-INF`

```
@Context ServletContext servletContext;
InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/fileName.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Although numerous different options you most likely want to refer to it on the classpath. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)