# How to read an array data from another file?

Tags: javascript, json

I contents of this site to the file at `App/data/names.js` directory in my solution: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dominictarr/random-name/master/names.json

I did it because the array is too big to put in my file where I write my code and initialize a variable with it explicitly.  But still, I would like to assign it to the variable I created. I have mind something like this.

```
var arrayOfNames = readJSonFromFile("path");
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading local JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Answer (score 1):

Like this!

```
$.getJSON('path', function (arrayOfNames) {
// do things with your arrayOfNames
} );
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` but yeah this will work: https://jsbin.com/javiyesupi/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Can I somehow do this synchronously?

Comment: With two different files?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the document with an HTTP request from JavaScript, sort of like this:

```
function do_something(arrayOfNames) {
  console.log(arrayOfNames)
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dominictarr/random-name/master/names.json', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      do_something(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
    }
  }
}
xhr.send()
```

Note that this may not work on ancient browsers. Depending on whether you're using some JavaScript framework there is probably a shorter solution.