# How to load a local JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I am trying to load a Local JSON file by jquery. the code works fine but the data are not available in array.

```
$.getJSON("/ajax/data/myjasonfile.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

my console shows only

```
Object {data: Array[1]}
```

my sample json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "number": "1234",
            "nameOne": "Laten Thamn",
            "type": "Fishing Vessels",
            "flagName": "5467",
            "buildDate":"12/08/2016"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "the data are not available in array" what do you mean ?

Comment: Do you mean local to the client machine? If so, this is not possible. If you mean local to the server, then what you have should work fine, assuming your path is valid.

Comment: The data should be available as an object. What does your console say

Comment: but i have above 100 records in the json

Comment: you should to check database query.

Comment: your array has only 1 element, maybe better remove [] characters?

Comment: this question is still not clear. Whats you issue? What excatly are you having trouble with here. Your simply logging an object. What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to understand your response structure.

```
 $.getJSON("myjasonfile.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json); // access the response object
        console.log(json.data); // access the array
        console.log(json.data[0]); // access the first object of the array
        console.log(json.data[0].number); // access the first object proprty of the array
    });
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

As you post in your JSON structure you can access to the array by calling `json.data`:

```
$.getJSON("/ajax/data/myjasonfile.json", function(json) {
     console.log(json.data); // Logs your array
});
```

Comment: If it's showing `Object {data: Array1}` it's already an object

Answer (score 0):

Store The json Data in Array:

```
 $.getJSON("/ajax/data/myjasonfile.json", function(Data) {
        var array=[];
    for(var i=1;i<Data.length;i++)
    {
        var b=Data[i];
        var c=[];
        c.push(b.number);
        c.push(b.nameOne);
        c.push(b.type);
        c.push(b.flagName);
        c.push(b.buildDate);
        array.push(c);
    }
        console.log(array);
    });
```

Comment: May I suggest you add some context explaining your answer?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
});
```

I think, Some issue is in your path to call json file. you need to check again of path.

You can check this link: [Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Comment: You should to follow above link. it will help you.

Comment: so your saying this is a duplicate?