# Can't read json in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, d3.js

I am trying to read json file using D3 library but when i try to read json i get alert Null Values (here i am using alert).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple venn.js example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="weighted_example"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
d3.json( "file.json", function( json ) {
  alert( "JSON Data: " + json );
});
</script>
</html>
```

Following is file.json (which is already validated online)

```
 [{
        "sets": [0],
        "size": 1958
    },
    {
        "sets": [1],
        "size": 1856
    },
    {
        "sets": [2],
        "size": 1297
    },
    {
        "sets": [0, 1],
        "size": 220
    },
    {
        "sets": [2, 0],
        "size": 123
    },
    {
        "sets": [2, 1],
        "size": 139
    }
 ]
```

How can i fix such issue?

Comment: use network tab in browser tools and check the file is being loaded you may be getting a 404

Comment: where is file.json? is it in same directory?

Comment: @man-data You must be betting error  XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
 "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Comment: @Dinesh yes they are in same directory

Comment: is that file loaded ? you can check that in developer tools network tab

Comment: NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

Comment: based your script, json file must be same level as .html file

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a browser you can't load local files. I suggest uploading the data somewhere online, like [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kvyb/d482dc15602c34841d4796daa9ed64cb/raw/d737e19c03868adf2f15103fcd98384f4c364785/file.json) and then request it with d3.json().

Likeso:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple venn.js example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="weighted_example"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
d3.json( "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kvyb/d482dc15602c34841d4796daa9ed64cb/raw/d737e19c03868adf2f15103fcd98384f4c364785/file.json", function(json) {
  alert( "JSON Data: " + json)
});
</script>
</html>
```

Otherwise you can hardcode it into your html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple venn.js example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="weighted_example"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
var json =  [{
        "sets": [0],
        "size": 1958
    },
    {
        "sets": [1],
        "size": 1856
    },
    {
        "sets": [2],
        "size": 1297
    },
    {
        "sets": [0, 1],
        "size": 220
    },
    {
        "sets": [2, 0],
        "size": 123
    },
    {
        "sets": [2, 1],
        "size": 139
    }
 ]

alert( "JSON Data: " + json)

</script>
</html>
```

If you don't mind using other libraries, there is a [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file) solution to loading locally, among others.

Comment: Vybrial i know how to use Jquery but i need to read using D3 as i am using D3 function. Can't i read json locally.

Comment: I am afraid there isn't a way with just D3.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get these files to work locally you will need to use an HTTP server. Personally I use MAMP for Mac machine.