# Read JSON file data on client side with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file on my local computer and I want to read its contents and display it on the web browser by using **pure javascript**. Anything which refers to the server side will not work for me. It is required to be done **purely on the Client Side**. What are the possible solutions ? 
Note: ajax and anything related to that should not be used.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Comment: I want to do it on the client side only with pure javascript and getJSON internally used ajax. First read this and then go somewhere else - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/      Also, before downvoting any question, just think about it, there are people who just don't accept what everybody says, they are also running there minds.

Comment: Maybe the author is asking not to use any JS library. Just pure Javascript.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't wanna do an `ajax` to load the file, and let user select the file what he wanna load by `<input type='file' />`, maybe this way is working for you.

```js
document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  var file = document.getElementById('myfile').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = evt.target.result;
  }
  
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" name="" id="myfile">
  
  <div id="content"></div>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function readFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                var value = JSON.stringify;
                // now display on browser :)
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile("file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt");
```

Comment: I have seen this. You must have copied it,and by the way XMLHttpRequest should not be used as I have to do it purely on client side