# Load a table with .json in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, scope

I am building my first ever website in `angularJs`. Currently, trying  to load a table using the following code

```
$scope.voyages = [
                {
    "data1": "data",
    "data2": "data
}, {
    "data1": "data",
    "data2": "data
}];
```

but I want to put the data from my `file.json` into this table, how can I do it?
I've tried the getJson function of jQuery but had no success, I might not be using it the correct or recommended way.

EDIT : Fixed it like this :

```
 function VoyagesCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.voyages= $.get( "file.json", function(data){
       $scope.voyages = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log($scope.voyages);
        });
    }
```

Comment: How did you tried to use the `getJSON` method?

Comment: I did it like that :             $scope.voyages = [];
            $.getJSON( "file.json", function( data){
            $scope.voyages = data;
            }); @rsz

Comment: That seems to be technically fine, what was the problem?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for help :)

Comment: How did you fix it? What was the problem? This could help others in the future who may stumble upon this question.

Comment: that way :  function VoyagesCtrl($scope) {
           $scope.voyages= $.get( "file.json", function(data){
           $scope.voyages = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log($scope.voyages);
            });
        }

Answer (score 0):

There's no absolute correct way to do it (depends on the situation). but I think what you're trying to do is use the data to locally test your angular app, for that you can check this answer here which is pretty much the same situation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18060563/7988438

What I'd advice though, is setting up a local server (using Node and Express) to serve your data, so you don't need to change the API calls once you're done with local testing, (use [this](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) if you're lazy, or if back-end isn't your thing), and getting them using AngularJS's [$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get).

Comment: Thank's for your nice help, i just fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var table_data =  $http.get('path-to-local-json', {}, 
{cache:false}).then(function(result){

       //return the data to the controller
       return result;
},function(err){
      //Handle errors.
});
```