# Loading an local JSON file offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, offline

So I have a client that wants a *site* that is not hosted anywhere but locally accessible via a browser (a html file in a folder). Now the tricky part is that they want to change this site on their own IN the browser. So I thought the best way to do this is to have a config locally. I created a `config.json` and went on to *get* it:

```
$.getJSON("config.json", function(config){
    //use config to alter the site
});
```

I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file) that modern browsers however block this kind of requests since it is considered unsafe. For example Chrome says:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Now the question is: How can I have a file that stores my config so that Javascript/jQuery can load it. Is there a way to ask the user to allow the fileaccess? Is there a completely different way of doing all this that suits the task better?

I'm looking forward to any suggestion as long as it is offline-compatible!

Comment: deploy the app on their local server. using any of http server like nodejs, tomcat etc.

Comment: could create an [Electron app](https://electronjs.org/) with same html , css and  js you are already using.

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't know about Electron and that's exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simplest solution: rename `config.json` to `config.js` for consistency

now, if the JSON is

```
{
    "configKey1": "value1"
}
```

wrap the json in a function,

```
function getconfig() { 
    return {
        "configKey1": "value1"
    };
}
```

now, simply have `<script src="config.js">` in your HTML

then, when you want to get config ... call `getconfig` to read it

```
let config = getconfig();
```

Comment: We can call it JSONP type implimentation :)

Comment: indeed, it actually is when you think about it :p