# Loading json data from file, using js locally

Tags: javascript, html, json, local

I have 3 files: *formData.json*, *myForm.html*, and *form.js*.
How can I take data from *.json* using JavaScript, and load it to my HTML `form` without any kind of server, just using Chrome? Is it even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but probably requires an entire tutorial rather than a simple answer, and many choices to be made depending on your requirements and experience.
See if  [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file) helps.