# How to write only pure JS(no jquery or anything) code for reading JSON data from external '.js' file?

Tags: javascript

Note : Using only pure JS, no addons, please provide a sample example

Sample data js file content -

```
var TABLE_DATA = [
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "cony #5",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/5.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "cony #1",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/1.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "cony #2",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/2.gif",
    "price": 270
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "cony #8",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/8.gif",
    "price": 70
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "<img onerror='window.document.body.innerHTML = \"<h1>XSS</h1>\";' src=''> ",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/10.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "cony #4",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/4.gif",
    "price": 150
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "cony #3",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/3.gif",
    "price": 130
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "cony #6",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/6.gif",
    "price": 160
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "cony #9",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/9.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "cony #7",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/7.gif",
    "price": 170
  }
]
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried

Comment: put you code between ``` in order to format it

Answer (score 2):

js has inbuilt `JSON.parse(YOUR_JSON_FILE)` method for parsing json.

In your example it is a json array.

So you may use for loop to go through each individual jsons.

```
        const length = TABLE_DATA.length;
        for(var i =0 ;i< length;i++) {
            var jsObject = JSON.stringify(TABLE_DATA[i]);
            console.log(jsObject);
    //To read id 
    console.log(jsObject.id)
    //To read name
    console.log(jsObject.name)
    //and so on   
}
```

> REMEMBER : `JSON.parse` turns a string of JSON text into a JavaScript
>   object
>
> `JSON.stringify` turns a JavaScript object into JSON text and stores
>   that JSON text in a string

To LOAD_IN data from file [click here : Loading Local Json File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

May it Help You!

Comment: the file with JSON data is a diff file and not within the same js file. I wanna know how to make that(diff file) JSON data accessible in another js file.

Comment: You may head over here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file

Comment: Please tick the answer if it helped you.@'Omkar Nilake'

Answer (score 1):

To load your external file, it must be made available on some place that your script is able to access (e.g. a web server). If you place the data as pure JSON (without `var TABLE_DATA`), you can load this data using the `XMLHttpRequest`, something along the lines of the following:

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState ==4  && this.status==200) { 
        data = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
        // do stuff with your data
    }
}
xhttp.open(URL_TO_THE_JSON)
xhttp.send()
```

Comment: It might be working but not able to test it as "CORS policy" issue is blocking it.

Comment: Are you working in a browser environment (with html)? In that case, you can just use the `script` tag to load the external file.