# XMLHttpRequest issue: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

Trying to get some data from a local JSON file stored in the same directory, I get this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///C:/Visual%20Studio%20Code/Practice/customer.json' from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>   https.
>
> app.js:14 GET file:///C:/Visual%20Studio%20Code/Practice/customer.json
>   net::ERR_FAILED

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Please fallow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers prohibit any kind of ajax from local files (resources loaded via the `file:` scheme). You appear to be using one of them.

The solution is to install a local webserver and load the resources via `http:` instead. Some IDEs have a minimal webserver included, either directly or via an extension. But if not, a local install of Apache or nginx is fairly easy to install, or you can roll your own with Express.js or Koa.js or similar.

This isn't the only subtle difference between how browsers handle `file:` resources vs. `http:`/`https:` resources, so when doing web development, it's always best to use a local web server, not `file:`.