# "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error when loading a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have an online implementation of an experiment in javaScript and it has to load the parameters for the task implementation from a JSON file. I found a way to do this but it works only when I run the task through a live server. If I run locally by opening the index.html file, I get the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///home/terraregina/Desktop/Space_Adv_Behav_PIlot_Online/config.json. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

My code for loading the JSON file is:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "config.json",
    success: function(data) {
        assignValues(data);   // extract vals from JSON file
        main();               // run experiment
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest issue: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60786555/xmlhttprequest-issue-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-sche)

Comment: If you aren't familiar woth CORS I recommend you read up on it. E.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. It's there to protect you but can be disabled for certain scenarios.

Comment: Run a local server!

Comment: @Edric I think I do essentially have the same problem but the solution is again to use a server. When I do that, everything runs fine and the final version will be run on a server framework anyways but until then I want to be able to run it locally too for certain reasons.

Comment: @epascarello, am I to understand that it is not possible to run it locally at all? Thanks to everyone for the quick responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ EDIT ]

Some modern browsers like *Chrome* prohibit to access local file with *Javascript* using `file:` scheme. Instead, You can use a simple web server to expose it. You can use some library like [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server#readme) to expose your local file.

Examples

1. Using NodeJS & NPM

```sh
npm i -g http-server
http-server your_config_folder
```

2. Using PHP (*Run this inside your folder*)

```sh
php -S localhost:8080
```

3. Using Python 3 (*Run this inside your folder*)

```sh
python -m http.server 8080
```

And then access `config.json` file from web browser:

http://localhost:8080/config.json

Comment: I'm a bit confused, my problem is that my task doesn't run when I open it locally (not through a server). Does your answer still apply? Thank you.