# Load Json data from local file into Typescript variable in REACT

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, loops, io

Excuse my lack of knowledge as i have never dealt with JSON arrays. I'm trying to load a JSON file data into a Typescript variable so i can do a certain treatment that uses arrays, but i have no idea how to do it, here's how the data is stored in my JSON file:

```
{"Array1":["A","B","C","D"] , "Array2":["W","X","Y","Z"]} //2 arrays
```

i want to have to keep the data exactly how it is so i can use it to loop through the arrays in my file.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file

Comment: JavaScript on the web doesn't have access to the local filesystem. If you're doing this from a browser, you'll need to fetch the file from a server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse('{"Array1":["A","B","C","D"] , "Array2":["W","X","Y","Z"]}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this data is inside a file, i want to load it from a local file

Comment: for loading data you must use ajax. see [getJson](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).