# Why am I getting a error saying "SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'" in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

Error I am getting:

> SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

This is what is in the JSON file:

```
{ "Name":"John", "Age":30 }
```

This is what is in the JavaScript file reading the data:

```
var jsonFile = JSON.parse(test);
var Tag = document.getElementById("test");

Tag.innerHTML = jsonFile.Name;
```

This is the HTML tags I have added in the HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/test.json" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/java.js" async></script>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/test.json" async></script>` this is wrong. You can't have json as script tag's src

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse is expecting a string such as

```
'{ "Name":"John", "Age":30 }'
```

Try the following for [reading a local json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .json() instead of parse().

```
test.json()
```

Comment: Still gives the the same error, sorry, it seems to be a error with the json file not the javascript