# Read JSON that is in website source in client-side vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, json, client

I have a simple JSON file sitting in a `data` folder within the source of my website. In a javascript script I want to read the JSON and update the DOM with the information inside. The file structure of my website is like this

```
css
design
html
  |____ category.html (this is where the script will be loaded)
js
  |____updateDomScript.js (this is the script that should be loaded)
src
  |____data
          |____jsonFile.json (this is the json that needs to be loaded)
```

I obviously can't use `require()` from `nodejs` because this is on the client side. I don't see how `FileReader` would work here. All I need to do is read this JSON file from `../src/data/jsonFile.json`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file

Comment: @HamzaKhuswan so I see that requirejs can only load javascript modules and not a JSON file, unless I'm completely missing something, and I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Look at the second answer if you don't want use `require`

Comment: @HamzaKhuswan the second answer uses requirejs, and from what i see that only works on other local javascript modules

Comment: How do you host your website?

Comment: @deecue im not sure yet but it's all in the same directory and the whole directory will likely be deployed... btw if you have suggestions as to how i should deploy it based on  the way it's setup i wouldn't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant the third answer, you can use fetch statement. If you are confused about fetch then I recommend you look it up online first.

```js
fetch("path/to/file")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```