# How to use vegaEmbed to embed an Altair visualization into html document?

Tags: javascript, html, altair, vega, vega-embed

I am trying to embed an Altair data visualization I created in Python, into an html document. I have followed the instructions on https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/saving_charts.html, specifically the json/VegaEmbed method.
The following is my code for the html so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Altair Embed Demo</h1>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
    vegaEmbed('#vis', 'C:/Users/myName/chart.json');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As can be seen here, the Altair visualization is saved as chart.json locally, and I am calling the vegaEmbed module on it.

However, the issue I'm having is that the resulting page does not output the Altair visualization. My path is correct, I have imported the correct module, and I have used vegaEmbed() properly (I think). Could someone give me guidance on this issue if they have had experience with Vega/Altair? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're encountering a security issue with your browser not allowing you to access local files. If you use a URL to a file hosted online, it will work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    vegaEmbed("#vis", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega-lite/next/examples/specs/bar.vl.json");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are some suggestions here on how to access local files in the browser, which you can explore to find the most appropriate solution for you [Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file).

You could also embed the vega spec directly instead of saving it as a separate file by inserting something like the following into the document (as in the documentation page you linked):

```json
    var spec = {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
      "config": {
        "view": {
          "continuousHeight": 300,
          "continuousWidth": 400
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/cars.json"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "Origin",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Horsepower",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Miles_per_Gallon",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": "point"
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess that the issue with embedding the vega spec directly for me, is that if my dataset is large then my codebase becomes large as well. I will attempt the first method you provided.