# unit testing with Jest, how do I use my local url?

Tags: json, typescript, unit-testing, url, ts-jest

I'm writing a unit test using jest. The function is a `loadJsonData()`. It takes in a string called URL at which the Json file can be found as well as whether or not to use user credentials. This is what my test looks like

```
it('should fetch JSON data successfully', async () => {
  const url = '../../data/mockData.json';
  const useCredentials = false;

  const result = await JsonLoader.loadJsonData(url, useCredentials);

  expect(result).toEqual({
    // expected data from mockData.json
    // ...
  });
});
```

I have my mockData.json file at the indicated relative directory, but I can't tell if it's working. How can I feed my function the actual relative directory to the mockData.json file instead of a standard html url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)