# Load JSON data for Google MAPS API v3

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

starting from the following example code (from https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#SimpleIcons)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHgCs40BzMLmN2-GpJ-liYfcYsas-VVsI&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    maxZoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                mapOptions);

  setMarkers(map, beaches);
}

/**
 * Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for
 * the order in which these markers should display on top of each
 * other.
 */

 var beaches = (function () {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': data.php,
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
    alert("OK, data loaded");
}); 



/*var beaches = [
  ['Stuttgart', 48.766700, 9.183330, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
*/
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/beachflag.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
      new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/beachflag_shadow.png',
      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
      new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML <area> element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

can I load the points from an external file?
Using this solution [load json into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177548/load-json-into-variable) I made the following:

```
var beaches = (function () {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': data.json,
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
})();
```

but the file beaches list doesn't seem to be a well formatted JSON file!
file data.json:

```
beaches: [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

Comment: what "file beaches"?  I don't see a link to one the format in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your current JSON:

- You use single quotes rather than double quotes. In JSON, strings must be wrapped in double quotes.
- Your "beaches" property must also be wrapped in quotes.
- You must make the JSON an object by wrapping it in curly brackets (`{}`).

Try the following JSON:

```
{
    "beaches": [
        [
            "BondiBeach",
            -33.890542,
            151.274856,
            4
        ],
        [
            "CoogeeBeach",
            -33.923036,
            151.259052,
            5
        ],
        [
            "CronullaBeach",
            -34.028249,
            151.157507,
            3
        ],
        [
            "ManlyBeach",
            -33.80010128657071,
            151.28747820854187,
            2
        ],
        [
            "MaroubraBeach",
            -33.950198,
            151.259302,
            1
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thaks! The JSON file is now valid but if I use it none flag appear on the map. I think that the data are not loaded from the file because if I write "alert("OK, data loaded");" after "return json;" the alert message is not showed when the page loads. I edited the first post including the HTML code.

Comment: If you write "anything" **after** return it never gets to "anything" because it has already returned. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a popular activity in Australia.  See the below:

[Bulk uploading markers from Excel with custom info boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17455936/1019635)

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.  Looks like you need to make it an object by enclosing it in {}.