# Bulk uploading markers from Excel with custom info boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to upload an Excel Spreadsheet containing student names their geolocations, and their "top skills" from an online class into the Google Javascript API.

Eventually, I want each location to have a popup box associated with it, displaying the student name and their top skills.

From what I can tell according to the API, I have to use Data Arrays like this to plot the markers:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

Then I could add these locations like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
    }
```

A couple of questions:

1. Is there a speedier way of uploading the Excel Spreadsheet Data into a Javascript format without manually writing each location?
2. How do I associate those specific locations with a student name and list of skills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a json to do this.  If you save an excel file as a .csv there are online converters that can change it to a json.  In the past I've done this on a project:

http://burdsgis.coffeecup.com/BluePlaques/bpWords.html

The json for the above looks like this:

```
var dec_markers = [

{
    "NewNumber": "1",
    "Title": "97",
    "Location": "Unknown",
    "Unveiler": "Unknown",
    "Date": "Unknown",
    "Sponsor": "Unknown",
    "TomEast": "-1.55167",
    "TomNorth": "53.7917",
    "Title2": "97",
    "TomURL": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/76/198148805_85d6ff5b44_m.jpg",
    "TomLink": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/44067831@N00/198148805/in/set-1439239/"
},
```

etc...

You can then call the json in your map.js:

```
        //For loop to run through marker data
    for (id in dec_markers) {

        var photo = '<a href="' + dec_markers[id].TomLink + '" target="_blank" title="' + dec_markers[id].Title +' by Tom.Smith, on Flickr"><img src="' + dec_markers[id].TomURL + '" alt="' + dec_markers[id].Title2 + '"></a>';

        var info =  '<div><h1>' + dec_markers[id].Title + '</h1><p><b>Date Unveiled: </b>'  + dec_markers[id].Date + "<br><b>Sponsor: </b>" + dec_markers[id].Sponsor + '</p>' + photo + '</div>';

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(dec_markers[id].TomNorth,dec_markers[id].TomEast);

        addMarker(latlng,dec_markers[id].Title,info);

        mc.addMarker(marker);
        }
```

I was scraping images from a Flickr album to populate the pop up boxes (using the Flickr API).

Google csv to json for a converter.
I'd also suggest using infobubble rather than infowindow as the former is more versatile.
For the clustering effect you can use MarkerClustererPlus for Google Maps V3

Comment: @Parseltongue Feel free to contact me if you have any trouble getting it working and links for the scripts / converter can be found in the references section in the above page (BluePlaques page)

Comment: I'll definitely be contacting you at some point-- what's best for you?  I don't have a lot of javascript experience, so I anticipate some hurdles.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Parseltongue, check my profile for my email address / link to contact.  No PM option on stack exchange and it looks like there never will be:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

I hope it's going alright.

Answer (score 1):

You can load information directly from Excel data file with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) and [XLSX.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) libraries.

For example, if you have Excel file with four columns with the following headers in row number 1 and all data in next rows:

- Student
- Latitude
- Longitude
- Mark

You can load it and process to Google Maps with the following code:

```
<script src="alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script>
    alasql('SELECT * FROM XLSX("students.xlsx",{headers:true})',[], function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].Latitude, data[i].Longitude),
                 map: map
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Alasql looks awesome! You can even use it with Tabletop.js to get data out of Google Drive spreadsheets: https://github.com/agershun/alasql#alasql-and-google-spreadsheets-with-tabletop

Answer (score 0):

From a point of view to 'give a data to script',
'uploading' may not required.
You just "copy" a simple text to clipboard of client PC.
Then,some security-loose browser can peek it as follows:

"clipboardData.getData('text');"

Or,If you do not want such a dangerous process,
You can make a visible pane like QA box of this page:

```
<span id=dp style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:8px;"></span>
$('#dp').html('<txtarea id=dt rows=20 cols=48>');
```

Then,paste some visible and clear data onto it,
finally you can process it by function "$('#dt').text()";
At end,please $('#dp').html('') to hide it.