# javascript variable is 'null' or 'undefined' after loading it from a local JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a javascript variable `my_jason` from the contents of a JSON file "gunsList.json" (both are stored within the same folder on my machine).

I seem to be having the same issue that the OP had in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484613/load-local-json-file-into-variable), which was resolved when he corrected his flawed JSON file.  Thinking I have the same issue, I ran my file through JSONLint (I'm assuming that's proper validation), and it came back clean.

Borrowing tips from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177548/load-json-into-variable), I tried using jQuery to get it done (*note*: I'm using jQuery successfully in other parts of the existing code), as follows:

```
var my_json;
$.getJSON('gunList.json', function(json) {
my_json = json;
});
```

When I try the method above (e.g., `alert(my_json)`), `my_json` is `undefined`.

Admittedly, I know very little about AJAX, but I also tried:

```
var my_json = (function () {
    var my_json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'gunsList.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            my_json = data;
        }
    });
    return my_json;
})();
```

In the case above, `my_json` is `null`.

All my code that references the array within "gunsList.json" when I paste it in as a variable in my js file runs fine, but as a fledgling programmer, I'd be really excited about getting it to work with JSON.

Comment: 1) Where and when are you doing the `alert`? Try it in the callback itself. 2) Provide an error handler for your `$.ajax` call and see if it's getting called.

Comment: is there an error in the browser console? one reason could be the ajax request is failed and error callback is called

Comment: It looks fine to me otherwise http://plnkr.co/edit/O1GB5untrFh82KtaUJuk?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's why your original `$.getJSON()` code didn't work - the comments show the order of execution and the value of `my_json` at each step:

```
var my_json;
// 1 - my_json is undefined
$.getJSON('gunList.json', function(json) {
    // 3 (!)
    my_json = json;
    // 4 - my_json now has the JSON data
});
// 2 - my_json is undefined (!)
```

As you can see, the function returns *before* the `my_json` value is set.

So you tried to fix it by using the `async: false` option on a `$.ajax()` call instead. But that is a very bad idea! Never use that option unless you have a *very* good reason for it: in many browsers, it will hang up not just your own site but all browser tabs and windows until your server returns the data.

Instead, let the `$.ajax()` or `$.getJSON()` call operate asynchronously, and do something with the data in the callback or in a function that you call from that callback. So, going back to your original `$.getJSON()` code, you can do this:

```
$.getJSON( 'gunList.json', function( json ) {
    // Do stuff with JSON data here, or call a function here and
    // pass the data to it as an argument
});
```

Comment: no, he has set the flag async to false that means it is not processed as an async request

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Ah, I missed that, thanks for pointing it out. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks Michael and company!