# Parsing values from external JSON file with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I have created a simple pie chart using Chart.js. I want to link this to a JSON file on my computer, which is in the same local folder. I then want the data from the JSON file to show up on my pie chart, instead of it being taken directly from the script.

How do I go about doing this? This is my code.

```
  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myDoughnutChart");
    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Orange", "Light Blue"],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: ["#0074D9", "#FF4136", "#2ECC40", "#FF851B", "#7FDBFF"],
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2],
                    }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                showAllTooltips: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Responsive test"
                    },
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                    fullWidth: true,
                    labels: {
                    boxWidth: [50]
                    },
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This is my JSON file, which is saved under "chart.json" - I am not sure if this is the correct format as I am a real newbie to this.

```
{"jsonarray": [{
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Value": 12}, 
    {
    "Color": "Red",
    "Value": 19}, 
    {
    "Color": "Green",
    "Value": 3}, 
    {
    "Color": "Orange",
    "Value": 5}, 
    {
    "Color": "Light Blue",
    "Value": 2}]
};
```

I understand a need to parse the JSON file but I have no idea how to do this - thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple parts here.

#### Step One: load the JSON from a file

I like using [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). If you use jQuery, you can also use [$.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484613/load-local-json-file-into-variable). Assuming the file is in the same directory as your JS code and is named `chart.json`:

```
  fetch('./chart.json')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (json) {
      // drawChart fn to be created...see below
      drawChart(json);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Note that if you are running this code locally, you will probably get an error about CORS if you try to visit the website directly from the filesystem (like `file:///<path-to-file>/index.html`).

Instead, you can run a local server easily. Go to the directory that contains your file in your terminal, and run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

or

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

This serves up the current directory on port 8000. Then visit http://localhost:8000/

Also, make sure the JSON is valid (no semicolon at the end!).

#### Step Two: parse the JSON response

We're trying to make two arrays. One with numbers for data, and one with strings for Labels.

You can do this easily with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var graphData = json.jsonarray.map(e => e.Color);
// ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Orange", "Light Blue"]
var graphLabels = json.jsonarray.map(e => e.Value);
// [12, 19, 3, 5, 2]
```

#### Step Three: bring it all together

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", draw);
function draw() {
  // Get the json file with fetch or $.ajax
  // Pass the json data to drawChart
}
function drawChart(jsonData) {
  /* get graphData and graphLabels
  draw chart with your existing code
  pass graphData and graphLabels in place of
  the hard-coded labels and data in your Chart initialization */
}
```

#### extending the idea:

Right now this code only supports a single dataset. The `backgroundColor` array is fixed, so if you do not have exactly 5 values, some of the background colors will be ChartJS's default gray.

You can further abstract the drawing code to support multiple datasets & even randomly generate colors to match the number of groups if you require it. Just swap out the hard-coded values as needed with variables you generate from your dataset. Hopefully this helps get you started!

Comment: That's great thank you for taking your time to break this down. My only question now is where in the code I input variables graphData and graphLabels? I am a complete newbie to this and have minimal JS knowledge, thanks again

Comment: You can wrap your current code in a function that takes these variables, like function drawGraph(graphData, graphLabels) { // your existing code }. Then in your existing code, replace the hard-coded values with the variables passed in. So data: {
                labels: ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Orange", "Light Blue"] becomes data: {
                labels: graphLabels
and the same replacement for the data.

Answer (score 0):

The json files are most of the time  string type so the chart you want to generate I think it needs a kind of number type so you need to convert your JSON data to a number time 
check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp),if you do the parsing of JSON correctly check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) how its already answered , you'll be ok .