# HTML not liking require().... When I use in index.js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This question is not the same as: [Load local JSON file into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484613/load-local-json-file-into-variable)

I've just tried implementing that change and nothing...

I've been finding that When I run my json string results through my web browser I'm getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I'm using Node.js as my platform for running this.

After looking into this I'm still no further forward. I don't want to use Browserfy or webpack. And I'm not using Jquery.

This works when I hard code my two json strings into index.js. However I'm need it to be variable.

I need a pure JavaScript way of reading the .json file without using require.
As I've seen

```
let fs = require('fs');
```

which will enable me to read the file however that's a require...

I have my HTML and Index.js files below if you can suggest anything.

**Webpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Out Put to HTML Page</title>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ='TestResults'>
    <div id = 'TestOutput'>Nothing Yet</div>
</div>
<div id ='ErrorResults'>
    <div id = 'ErrorOutPut'>Nothing Yet</div>
</div>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.js**

```
let myJsonString = require('../../ResultsArray/ResultsArray');
let myJsonStringError = require('../../ResultsArray/ErrorArray');

function result(results){
    if(results === 'YesNo')
    {
        return 'Passed'
    }
    if(results === 'NoYes')
    {
        return 'Failed'
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Unknown'
    }
}

function time (value){
    // 1- Convert to seconds:
    let seconds = (value / 1000).toFixed(2);
    // 2- Extract hours:
    let hours = parseInt( seconds / 3600 ); // 3,600 seconds in 1 hour
    seconds = seconds % 3600; // seconds remaining after extracting hours
    // 3- Extract minutes:
    let minutes = parseInt( seconds / 60 ); // 60 seconds in 1 minute
    // 4- Keep only seconds not extracted to minutes:
    seconds = (seconds % 60).toFixed(2);
    return ([hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds]);
}

function testTemplateErrors (test){
    return `
    <tr>
    <td class='TestGroup'>${test.Folder}</td>
    <td class='TestName'>${test.Test_Name}</td>
    <td class='TestsStatus'>${test.Running}</td>
    <td class='TestRunTime'>${time(test.Run_Time)}</td>
    <td class= 'TestResult'>${result(test.Passed + test.Failed)}</td>
    </tr>
    `
}

function testTemplateResults (test){
    return `
    <tr>
    <td class='TestGroup'>${test.Folder}</td>
    <td class='TestName'>${test.Test_Name}</td>
    <td class='TestsStatus'>${test.Running}</td>
    <td class='TestRunTime'>${time(test.Run_Time)}</td>
    <td class= 'TestResult'>${result(test.Passed + test.Failed)}</td>
    </tr>
    `
}

if(myJsonString && myJsonString.length)
{
    document.getElementById('TestResults').innerHTML = `
    <h1 class='ContentTitle'> Regression Tests (${myJsonString.length} Tests Ran)</h1>
    <table><tr>
    <th>Result Folder Name</th>
    <th>Result Test Name</th>
    <th>Result Running</th>
    <th>Result Run Time</th>
    <th>Result Result</th>
    </tr><tr>
    ${myJsonString.map(testTemplateResults).join('')}
    </tr></table>
    <p class='footer'> These ${myJsonString.length} Results were added recently. </p>
    `
}

if(myJsonStringError && myJsonStringError.length)
{
    document.getElementById('ErrorResults').innerHTML = `
    <h1 class='ContentTitle'> Error Results (${myJsonStringError.length} Errors Occurred)</h1>
    <table><tr>
    <th>Error Folder Name</th>
    <th>Error Test Name</th>
    <th>Error Running</th>
    <th>Error Run Time</th>
    <th>Error Result</th>
    </tr><tr>
    ${myJsonStringError.map(testTemplateErrors).join('')}
    </tr></table>
    <p class='footer'> These ${myJsonStringError.length} Results were added recently. </p>
    `
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load local JSON file into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484613/load-local-json-file-into-variable)

Answer (score 0):

`require` is provided by Node.js, not by browsers, and also by bundlers like Webpack or Browserify. If you're running browser-based code and not using one of those tools or RequireJS, it will not exist in the browser environment.

To read a resource from browser-based code, you'd use ajax. The modern way to do that is to use `fetch` (previously, you'd use `XMLHttpRequest`). Here's a simple `fetch` example for something returning JSON:

```
fetch("/url/to/the/resource")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error: " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    // ...use the data here, it's been parsed...
})
.catch(error => {
    // Something went wrong, handle/report it
});
```

As I [note on my anemic blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html), it's very easy to forget that `.ok` check and tedious to re-code it all the time, so I use a helper:

```
const myFetch = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error: " + response.status);
    }
});
```

...which you'd use like this to fetch JSON:

```
myFetch("/url/to/the/resource")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    // ...use the data here, it's been parsed...
})
.catch(error => {
    // Something went wrong, handle/report it
});
```

If you want to fetch multiple resources and wait for them all to arrive, use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([
    myFetch("../../ResultsArray/ResultsArray.json").then(response => response.json()),
    myFetch("../../ResultsArray/ErrorArray.json").then(response => response.json())
])
.then(([resultsArray, errorArray]) => {
    // ...use `resultsArray` and `errorArray` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

All of those examples assume ES2015-ES2017. If you can use ES2018 features, taht code can be more synchronous-looking using an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Note that `fetch` (like `XMLHttpRequest`) is *asynchronous*; these questions may help with issues you may have as a result of that:

- [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [*Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: When I've altered my index.js file to show your changes I get back "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". even though they are in the location specified.

Comment: @Daniel - If you're getting a 404, the URL is wrong. My guess is you're missing out a file extension (`.json` or `.js`), since they weren't on your `require` calls (Node.js infers `.js` if you leave it off; browsers don't).

Comment: Ok I tried this:
`fetch("../../ResultsArray/ErrorArray.json")
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error: " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        myJsonString = data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error.json could not be found');
    });`

And I get the .jsons in the Network tab when I inspect the html page however Its not linking to my json string within the index.js file.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't know what you mean by *"...Its not linking to my json string within the index.js file..."* The data from the JSON files is accessible where I showed above (and not globally). See the linked questions at the end of the answer for more details on that, as indicated.

Comment: I've added in another explanation as to what I mean.

Comment: @Daniel - If you mean the answer you posted, that's usually not best practice, because the variables will have the value `undefined` until / unless the fetches complete. Again, see the questions linked at the end of the answer above. But yes, you *can* do what you do in that answer; that's just one of many ways you might "use" the results as indicated in my answer.

Comment: Could I wrap that in a promise and resolve upon data being brought back?

Answer (score -1):

I tried to set the response from the fetch to a variable:

```
let myJsonString;
let myJsonStringError;

fetch("../../ResultsArray/ResultsArray.json")
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error: " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        myJsonString = data;
        console.log(myJsonString);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Results.json could not be found');
    });

fetch("../../ResultsArray/ErrorArray.json")
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error: " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        myJsonStringError = data;
        console.log(myJsonStringError);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error.json could not be found');
    });
```

And I can see the .Json files in my network tab.
[Network Tab results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRcA2.png)