# Add local json file to fetch objects in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Hi I would like to know what is best way to fetch JSON objects from a local file which is in a below format to render list of Key value airs from those JSON list. I tried to import file as mentioned below but it goes in vain. I want to know how to fetch those key value pairs form local json file to display using jsx. any leads would be appreciated. for instance if i want to display "John got calls from the United states at 12.20 pm". Where John is passed as name ID under Calls,location under States and so on.

```
{"Calls":[there are list of key values pairs
],
"States":[there are a list of key value pairs],
"time:[list of key value pairs]"}
```

React code:

```
import jsonData from "./example.json";

const loadData = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userList: []
    };
   }

   componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('./example.json') // JSON File Path
      .then( response => {
        this.setState({
        userList: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
   }

   render() {
  const usersList = this.state.userList;
  let usersListBlock = '';

  if(usersList.length > 0) {
    usersListBlock = usersList.map( obj => {
      return (
        <Usercard key={obj.id} id={obj.id} id={obj.number} name={obj.name} />
            )
    })
   }

   return(
    <div className="row container">
        {usersListBlock}
    </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Simply importing like `import jsonData from "./example.json";` and using jsonData would work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484613/load-local-json-file-into-variable

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use json file by importing and then you can use json object directly or set it in state.
Import Json file like you have already done

```
import jsonData from "./example.json";
```

and then in set it in state or use directly

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({userList:jsonData })

   }
```

Comment: Yes, I tried react DOM does not recognize this path and can not find the file content.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to save JSON file in public folder and just call it with axios.get('example.json'), it worked for my just fine.