# How to import .json file into to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following json file which is generated as a result of some python code . (I basically transfer a dict into a json file)

```
{"workers dwell time": [{"Arham": 0.0}, {"Fayyaz Bhai": 3.28}, {"Khan sahab": 2.14}, {"Osama": 0.0}, {"Yasir (paadri)": 0.0}]}
```

The json file is named as workers_dwell_time_final.json

I want to import this file into javascript. And assign the names to the respective times in  table.

**Mainly i want to know how to import the json file into javascript ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load local JSON file into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484613/load-local-json-file-into-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of a million other questions and articles on google.

Comment: if you expect changes in the JSON file better not to import but read it.

Answer (score -1):

data.json content
`const data = [{"name" : "lily", "address" : "location street"}];`

and use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
```

also
use `XMLHttpRequest` read local json file

Comment: JSON isn't JavaScript. This will likely throw a CORB error.