# angular can't find node_modules library sub-folder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to import some json files that are within sub-folders of a library inside node_modules, and typescript is saying it can't find the sub-folder.

The library is cldr-data, and the specific path I need is cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json.

[image: browser location]

I've tried the following imports:

```
import likelySubtags from 'cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json';
import likelySubtags from './../../node_modules/cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json';
```

but both give the error: [ts] Cannot find module. The strange thing is it can find cldr-data, it just can't find the sub-folder supplemental. I'm not sure how to make it find supplemental/.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540064/190327 I think you have to resolve json module

Comment: Ah, I tried that with no luck. It can't even find the supplemental folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare the application with additional flags in your `tsconfig.json` beforehand. You should add additional compiler options:

**ResolveJSONModule**

`--resolveJsonModule` allows for importing, extracting types from .json files.

**ESModuleInterop**

`--esModuleInterop` Allows default imports from modules with no default export. This is required since a .json file has no default output.

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
 "esModuleInterop": true
```

Now in component you can use :

```
import likelySubtags from 'cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix my problem. It can't find the supplemental folder at all: Cannot find module 'cldr-data/supplemental/'