# Loading GeoJson Google API - CORS policy

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to load some JSON with Google maps API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

This is my code on fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/simonrenauld/3z7peqdv/6/

```
<script src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/jsontestdemp/testdata.jsonp"></script>
```

I have tried to load as geojsonp like in the documentation

I am still not able to load into my map. What's the easy solution here to avoid the CORS policy?

Comment: Load the GeoJSON from the same domain, or from one that you can control (to set the CORS headers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#sample_geojson):

> Note: In order to load a json file from another domain, that domain
>   must have enabled [Cross-origin resource
>   sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Otherwise, load it from the same domain. E.g. check out this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-sammet-sbn73) that loads Google's GeoJSON sample from a file (`myjson.json`) located at the same root-level as `index.html`.

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: { lat: -28, lng: 137 }
    });

    map.data.loadGeoJson("myjson.json");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes correct if transferring from a local test site to live URL the code needs to reflect the new address. https://www.localsite.com/myfile.geojson >> https://www.livesite.com/myfile.geojson. Then don't forget to upload geojson file to live server.