# How can I read a JSON without parent root name with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file which has this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "customer":{
         "nickname":"nick001",
         "email":"",
         "id":"15615",
         "name":"Smith Dole",
         "phone":"5555555"
      },
      "totalorder":"44155",
      "items":[
         {
            "code":"041545420",
            "title":"item",
            "quantity":1,
            "price":"2461.7500",
            "subtotal":2461.75
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see it doesn´t have any parent root name. How can I read this JSON with JavaScript ?

I was thinking to PARSE the Json but JSON.parse(need the name)

Is it possible to call this JSON in my JavaScript code and asign it a variable ?

var newSelling = data from the JSON

The JSON is being generated by another system which generates it that way so I need to read the JSON to get the data needed for other processes

the JSON is automatically generated and it is in an external file

Comment: It's an array so basicly `newSelling[0]`

Comment: You have an array of objects.

Comment: @Halil Çakar The JSON is automatically generated and it is in an external file. How can I add it newSelling[0] ?

Comment: Is this a node project or a browser based one? if it's node based you can require() to a variable and use it as an array. If it's a json and coming from request then it will be array again so it depends

Comment: @Halil Çakar Json file is left that way in a folder. So I have to set the path in order to read the JSON

Comment: Again, Is this a nodejs project? or do you need to read it from a browser?

Comment: @Halil Çakar I need to read it from a browser. It is not a nodejs project

Comment: Well browsers doesn't have the ability to read a file directly, so you can make a get request to full path of json and inside response you will have your array :) you can maybe check here https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-to-get-json-data-from-a-website/153769/2

Comment: So load it with fetch

Answer (score 1):

So it is a JSON file. Request it with fetch or XMLHttpRequest and access the JSON.

```
fetch('/path/to/your/file.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the file in the **Browser** from your local you can use one of these solutions :

- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
- [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).
- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

I recommend Fetch API.

```
      fetch("data.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json));
```

It works in Firefox, but in Chrome you have to customize security setting.

Answer (score -1):

If you look carefully, you'll see that this JSON file is just a JSON array with only one Object inside of it. So you have to access the object that is in the array.

```
let arr = JSON.parse(*the json object*);
let obj = arr[0];
```

I haven't tested this, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: The JSON is automatically generated and it is in an external file

Answer (score -1):

Here in your case, using JSON.parse only is not working
but the combination of **JSON.stringify** and **JSON.parse** is working as I tried.
So first, we can stringify it and then we can parse it

Like this :

```
var a = [
   {
      "id":"1",
      "customer":{
         "nickname":"nick001",
         "email":"",
         "id":"15615",
         "name":"Smith Dole",
         "phone":"5555555"
      },
      "totalorder":"44155",
      "items":[
         {
            "code":"041545420",
            "title":"item",
            "quantity":1,
            "price":"2461.7500",
            "subtotal":2461.75
         }
      ]
   }
];

var b = JSON.stringify(a);
var c = JSON.parse(b);
console.log(c[0].id); //output : 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Parsing JSON should work as follows:

```
const json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.count);
// expected output: 42

console.log(obj.result);
// expected output: true
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Edit:
You can red this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484613/load-local-json-file-into-variable). I think it may help

Comment: The JSON is automatically generated and it is in an external file