# Pulling data from json file to use in .$post in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, post, playframework-2.0

I'd like to pull data from a json file to post it to the server side.

This kind of data decleration works:

```
$.post('/createDBJSON',{'name':'bar'},
function(data) {window.alert(data);}
```

However I need something like this:

```
$.post('/createDBJSON',{'/assets/appconf/db.json'},
function(data) {window.alert(data);}
```

I know $.post gets data as PlainObject or String but I want to somehow post data as json file because my json file is very complex (too many embedded key-val pairs) to easily parse to js variable(s) using $.getJSON to use in in $.post as documented.

Is there another approach I should consider in order to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This link may usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177548/load-json-into-variable

Comment: This is very weird. You want to pull json from the server (`db.json`), and then push it back to the server in a `post` request, without even parsing it into an object locally? It seems like you should add some functionality on the server side, to avoid this useless transfer of data.

Comment: I think I'm doing something stupid. I should use a JSON parser in server side without involving client side in the first place. I've found some docs regarding GSON to parse JSON data. Do you have a suggestion like this in order to use it in Play Framework 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be hitting a subtle issue with `$.post()` when the data is an object. It gets converted to a string, but not to a JSON string - rather, it is used as a set of key-value pairs for building a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string.

Another issue with `$.post()` is that it always sends a content-type header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. This might be the reason why the server is crashing: it's expecting JSON, but the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To fix this we can use the more general `$.ajax()` which has more options.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('/assets/appconf/db_trial.json', function(firstData) 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/createDBJSON',
        data: JSON.stringify(firstData), // send JSON representation
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // set correct content-type header
        success: function(secondData) {window.alert(secondData);}
    });
});
```

We could also try another method which never bothers to convert the first json response into an object and then back into a json string, instead just keep it as text the whole time:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "text", // parse response only as text
    url: '/assets/appconf/db_trial.json',
    success: function(jsonString) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/createDBJSON',
            data: jsonString, // jsonString is already a json string
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // set correct content-type header
            success: function(secondData) {window.alert(secondData);}
        });
    }
});
```

Please try both!

But I still recommend fixing your back-end so the data doesn't pass through the client for no reason! I think Play Framework 2 includes Jackson for JSON manipulation, so you just need to import the right classes, and search the internet to learn how to read JSON files with the Jackson library.

Answer (score 2):

You could use $.getJSON like this:

```
$.getJSON('/assets/appconf/db.json', function(json) {

     $.post('/createDBJSON',json,
     function(data) {window.alert(data);}

});
```

Comment: It seems working in POST perspective. Do you know how to parse it in play 2.1? JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();String name = json.findPath("style_nodes").getTextValue(); seems to fail on that.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my content type was not json. It needs to be specified. Play 2.1 json body parse example works as documented. I wish that they provide the proper client call example as well...

Here is the working ajax call:

```
$.getJSON('/assets/appconf/db_trial.json', function(json) 
{
    $.ajax({
          url:'/createDBJSON',
          type:"POST",
          data:JSON.stringify(json),
          contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(){

          }
        });

});
```