# Is there a way to get external data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have minimal knowlege of javascript so please be kind.
I have created a very basic javascript that show a random quote from a politician, who said it, when, and it provides a link to the source of the quote.
It looks something like that:

```
/the quote
var n_text = new Array ();
/the link
var n_lnkk = new Array ();
/the party member that said it and when
var n_part = new Array ();

n_text [1]="blah";
n_text [2]="blah blah";
n_text [3]="blah blah blah";
etc

n_lnkk [1]="http://...";
n_lnkk [2]="http://...";
n_lnkk [3]="http://...";
etc

n_part [1]="whosaidit1";
n_part [2]="whosaidit2";
n_part [3]="whosaidit3";
etc
```

Then I use math.random and document.write to show a random quote and show a twitter button so that people can tweet it, and a refresh button to show another random quote like this:

blah blah
http://...
whosaidit and when

I know document.write is not the best way to do it but I have tried other methods and they didn't work with the twitter button so that will have to wait untill I find a solution for it but it is not the question I have right now.

The problem is that this script has become huge, (almost 1000 quotes) so blogger doesn't allow me to add any more text into it.
Is there a way to put the data in an external file somewhere and have the javascript read it and display the results and still keep it relatively simple since I have very basic knowledge of jscript or html?
Please keep in mind that I am using blogger so I have limited options, but I think an external file with just the data would work

Comment: By somewhere do you mean another file on the server or a different server.

Comment: Two buzzwords: [*Ajax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) and [*JSON*](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 1):

It would be really easy actually, just copy and paste your arrays and what you set them as into a separate .js file. Only copy up to where you have your document.write. Then include it in your  tag...

```
<script src="http://HostedSomewhere/Quotes.js"></script>
```

Make sure that is included BEFORE your old code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put the data in an external file. I would suggest a [JSON file](http://www.json.org).

What you'll want to do is either call the JSON file as such:

```
$.getJSON("link/to/json/file.json", variableOrFunctionNameHere);
```

OR

```
$.getJSON("link/to/json/file.json", function(d){...logic here...});
//the d is the data from the file.
```

However, this might not always work, so I'd look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177548/load-json-into-variable) for how to load it non-asynchronously.

Now, to use the JSON file, you'll need to learn some notation.

Let's say you set the JSON file up like this:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Chris Christie",
        "quote": "I closed the bridge!",
        "date" : "February 1, 2014",
        "link" : "https://somelinktosomewhere.com"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Hillary Clinton",
        "quote": "Vote for me if I run next election!",
        "date" : "March 31, 2014",
        "link" : "https://somelinktosomewhere.com"
    },    
]
```

and that the JSON file gets loaded in the variable called `myVariable`. Then, to access it, you'd find a random number within the size of the JSON file (each selection within brackets is an object) and then `myVariable[randomNumber].name` would access the name attribute of the file. So, for example, `myVariable[0].name` would return the String `"Chris Christie"`. JSON files are really powerful and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a simple and practical solution. An `iFrame` did it.
I hosted my script on a free server and then used an `iFrame` to get it on my blog. It was the first answer I got, but it seems to have been deleted since.

Comment: @yenshirak: This isn't a thank you, since the original is not present.