# Find highest value from a key in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var questions = [{
    'question_id': 245,
    'question': 'Question 1',
    'ordinal': 1,
    'master_difficulty': 1,
    'overridden_difficulty': ''
},{
    'question_id': 34,
    'question': 'Question 2',
    'ordinal': 2,
    'master_difficulty': 1,
    'overridden_difficulty': ''
},{
    'question_id': 656,
    'question': 'Question 3',
    'ordinal': 3,
    'master_difficulty': 1,
    'overridden_difficulty': ''
},{
    'question_id': 86,
    'question': 'Question 4',
    'ordinal': 4,
    'master_difficulty': 1,
    'overridden_difficulty': ''
}]
```

And I want to get the highest ordinal value from it.

e.g. `var highestOrdinal = highestOrdinalFunction(questions);`

Where `highestOrdinalFunction` will return the highest ordinal number.

So in this case it would return `4`.

Could `Math.max` work for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949597/getting-max-values-in-json-array

Comment: `Math.max.apply(Math, questions.map(q => q.ordinal));`

Comment: @Yoshi: Should have posted that as an *answer*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought there has to be ton's of duplicates for this question, so I expected it to get closed very quick.

Comment: @Yoshi: That's a fair point, and Ahbap had already found it for us as well.

Answer (score 4):

`Array#reduce` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)) is the idiomatic way to do things like this:

```
function highestOrdinalFunction() {
    return questions.reduce(function(previous, entry) {
        return previous === undefined || entry.ordinal > previous ? entry.ordinal : previous;
    }, undefined);
}
```

`Array#reduce` calls a callback repeatedly, passing in the callback's previous return value, which is seeded with the second argument to `reduce`. That thing is usually called the "accumulator" for the reduce operation. The result of `reduce` is the final value of the accumulator.

The above will return `undefined` if `questions` is empty.

Comment: What if ordinal values present in between `-2`  to `-infinity` ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Good point!!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

`Math.max.apply(Math,questions.map(function(ques){return ques.ordinal;}))`

please refer to [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more info on how map() works.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>We can just sort the objects within that array by the `ordinal` value and then return the first entry.</strike>

```
function highestOrdinalFunction( questions ) {
    return questions.sort( ( a, b ) => a.ordinal - b.ordinal )[ 0 ].ordinal;
}
```

It's probably a better idea to combine `Array.prototype.map` alongside `Math.max()` in this instance:

```
Math.max.apply( null, questions.map(q => q.ordinal) );
```

Comment: Sorting is an *awful* lot of work to do just to find the highest one.

Comment: You're right TJ, math.max seems to fit better.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the max value two ways. You can either pass a function to map the property's value or call the property directly on the item. The result of these would be the mapped value to be applied the the `Math.max` calculation, in respect to the list of items.

### Math.prototype.max

```js
var questions = [
  {'question_id':245,'question':'Question 1','ordinal':1,'master_difficulty':1,'overridden_difficulty':''},
  {'question_id':34,'question':'Question 2','ordinal':2,'master_difficulty':1,'overridden_difficulty':''},
  {'question_id':656,'question':'Question 3','ordinal':3,'master_difficulty':1,'overridden_difficulty':''},
  {'question_id':86,'question':'Question 4','ordinal':4,'master_difficulty':1,'overridden_difficulty':''}
]

document.body.innerHTML =  'Via Function: ' + highestOrdinalValueFn(questions) + '\n';
document.body.innerHTML += 'Via Property: ' + highestOrdinalValueProp(questions);

// #1 : Via function
function highestOrdinalValueFn(items) {
  return max(items, function() {
    return this.ordinal;
  });
}
// #2 : Via property
function highestOrdinalValueProp(items) {
  return max(items, 'ordinal');
}

function max(list, prop) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, list.map(function(item) {
    return isFunction(prop) ? prop.call(item) : item[prop];
  }));
}

function isFunction(fn) {
  return fn && {}.toString.call(fn) === '[object Function]';
}
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

---

### Array.prototype.reduce

```js
var questions = [
  {'question_id':245,'question':'Question 1','ordinal':1,'master_difficulty':1,'overridden_difficulty':''},
  {'question_id':34,'question':'Question 2','ordinal':2,'master_difficulty':1,'overridden_difficulty':''},
  {'question_id':656,'question':'Question 3','ordinal':3,'master_difficulty':1,'overridden_difficulty':''},
  {'question_id':86,'question':'Question 4','ordinal':4,'master_difficulty':1,'overridden_difficulty':''}
]

document.body.innerHTML = highestValue(questions, 'ordinal');

function highestValue(items, prop) {
  return compare(items, function(curr, prev) {
    return maxNumericComparator(curr, prev, prop);
  })[prop];
}

function maxNumericComparator(curr, prev, prop) {
  if (curr && !prev) return -1;
  if (!curr && prev) return 1;
  if (curr[prop] && !prev[prop]) return -1;
  if (!curr[prop] && prev[prop]) return 1;
  if (curr[prop] > prev[prop]) return -1;
  if (curr[prop] < prev[prop]) return 1;
  return 0;
};

function compare(list, comparator) {
  return list.reduce(function(max, item) {
    return comparator(item, max) < 0 ? item : max;
  }, null);
}
```