# How to get the max and min Value from any property in a JSON object with wildcard

Tags: javascript, json

I need to get the max and min values from all properties that end in **Count** from a JSON object similar to this. I would expect to get 18 as the max and 3 as the min.

I am able to get the max for an individual property ([Getting max value(s) in JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949597/getting-max-values-in-json-array)) but not for anything ending in **Count**.

```
[
{Period: 01/2017, Alpha: 5, AlphaCount: 10, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 7, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 3}
{Period: 02/2017, Alpha: 2, AlphaCount: 4, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 6, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 13}
{Period: 03/2017, Alpha: 6, AlphaCount: 8, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 12, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 18}
]
```

Comment: What would be an expected result at your data set?

Answer (score 1):

you can loop through the entire array and get keys for each object, use `indexOf()` to check if 'Count' is in the key and then check if it is max. something like this:

```js
var arr = [
{Period: 01/2017, Alpha: 5, AlphaCount: 10, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 7, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 3},
{Period: 02/2017, Alpha: 2, AlphaCount: 4, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 6, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 13},
{Period: 03/2017, Alpha: 6, AlphaCount: 8, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 12, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 18}
];
var max = -1;
arr.forEach(function(ob){
   var keys = Object.keys(ob);
   keys.forEach(x => max = x.indexOf('Count')>=0 && ob[x] >max ? ob[x]:max);
})
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Thank you! Very short and simple

Comment: @stanggt3 you are welcome, consider accepting the answer if it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sample = [
  {Period: '01/2017', Alpha: 5, AlphaCount: 10, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 7, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 3},
  {Period: '02/2017', Alpha: 2, AlphaCount: 4, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 6, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 13},
  {Period: '03/2017', Alpha: 6, AlphaCount: 8, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 12, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 18}
]

const arr = []
function extractCount (item) {
  return Object.keys(item).forEach(i =>  {
    /Count$/.test(i) && arr.push(item[i]);
  })
}

sample.map(extractCount)

console.log(Math.max(...arr));
console.log(Math.min(...arr));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Wrote an extended version just to see how each part works, from here you can modify to your liking, hope this helps:

```js
var arr = [
{Period: 01/2017, Alpha: 5, AlphaCount: 10, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 7, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 3},
{Period: 02/2017, Alpha: 2, AlphaCount: 4, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 6, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 13},
{Period: 03/2017, Alpha: 6, AlphaCount: 8, Bravo: 3, BravoCount: 12, Charlie: 9, CharlieCount: 18}
];

function getMaxThatEndsWith(arr, ending) {
 var maxVal;
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var obj = arr[i];
  var matches = getFieldsThatEndWith(obj, ending);
  for (var j = 0; j < matches.length; j++) {
   if (!maxVal || parseInt(obj[matches[j]]) > maxVal) {
    maxVal = obj[matches[j]];
   }
  }
 }
 return maxVal;
}

function getFieldsThatEndWith(obj, like) {
 var matches = [];
 var propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
 for(var i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
  var propName = propertyNames[i];
  if (propName.endsWith(like)) {
   matches.push(propName);
  }
 }
 return matches;
}

var maxValue = getMaxThatEndsWith(arr, 'Count');

console.log(maxValue);
```