# Store JSON data into a variable

Tags: json, angularjs, factory

I am new to AngularJS. I just want to load the JSON file data into a variable that is located in factory.

```
myApp.factory('quizFactory', function () {
    var questions = [
        {
            "setId":1,
            "question":"What is the value of the 7 in the following number? 850,765",
            "options": ["70", "7", "7000", "700"],
            "answer": 3
        },
        {
            "setId":2,
            "question":"Is 7 & 9 even or odd?",
            "options": ["Even", "Odd", "Can't Say", "Dont know"],
            "answer": 1
        },
        {
            "setId":3,
            "question":"In the number 5,281,946 what is the value of the 3rd place?",
            "options": ["100", "10,000", "1,000,000", "1,000"],
            "answer": 0 
        },
        {
            "setId":4,
            "question":"Is 12 + 50 even or odd?",
            "options": ["Even", "Odd", "Can't Say", "Dont know"],
            "answer": 0 
        },
        {
            "setId":5,
            "question":"What does the 3 represent in the number below? 3051",
            "options": ["3", "30", "300", "3000"],
            "answer": 3 
        }
    ];

    return {
        getQuestion: function(id) {
            if(id < questions.length) {
                return questions[id];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The above code is stored in app.js file and my JSON file is same as the above.

```
[


{
        "setId":1,
        "question":"What is the value of the 7 in the following number? 850,765",
        "options": ["70", "7", "7000", "700"],
        "answer": 3
    },
    {
        "setId":2,
        "question":"Is 7 & 9 even or odd?",
        "options": ["Even", "Odd", "Can't Say", "Dont know"],
        "answer": 1
    },
    {
        "setId":3,
        "question":"In the number 5,281,946 what is the value of the 3rd place?",
        "options": ["100", "10,000", "1,000,000", "1,000"],
        "answer": 0 
    },
    {
        "setId":4,
        "question":"Is 12 + 50 even or odd?",
        "options": ["Even", "Odd", "Can't Say", "Dont know"],
        "answer": 0 
    },
    {
        "setId":5,
        "question":"What does the 3 represent in the number below? 3051",
        "options": ["3", "30", "300", "3000"],
        "answer": 3 
    }
];
```

I have tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177548/load-json-into-variable) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to read json file. E.g.

```
$http.get('someFile.json').success(function(data) {    
        questions = data;
    });
```

Comment: I replaced my JS file from above with myApp.factory('quizFactory',['$http', function ($http) {
 $http.get('ques.json').success(function(data) {    
        var questions = data;
    });
}); but still not working it is unable to load the json file

Comment: It should work, may be your json file is not in the correct place. Here is the working demo http://plnkr.co/edit/PpRvBhbZ9LHT8EQeUV2a?p=preview

Comment: In the app.js file if I change app.controller to app.factory it is not working

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions can u help where should i add the controller data in this http://plnkr.co/edit/fOJoCVuIksmD3LSnGqBt?p=catalogue myApp.directive file

Comment: I would be glad to help :) , could you please post a new question describing what's the problem

Comment: hi @sol4me this is the actual question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396533/load-json-data-into-the-factory-file

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine your factory like this :

```
  angular.module('yourmodule')
 .factory('jsonResourceService', ['$http',
function($http) {
  var jsonResourceService = {};

  jsonResourceService.load = function(callback) {
    $http.get('path/data.json').success(function(data) {
      callback(data);
    });
   return jsonResourceService;


}
]);
```

and call it from your controller like this :

```
     $scope.objectsArray = [];

  jsonResourceService.load(function(data) {
 $scope.objectsArray;
});
```

Comment: why need forEach loop? instead you can directly store data into array object.

Comment: Edited just now in my case i was doing some extra processing before adding it to the array .

Answer (score 0):

If I want to add the JSON data to the factory variable on the some particular request inside a controller is what you meant, then `$http`  is the preferable one:

```
     appmodule.controller('appCtrl',   ['$http','quizFactory',function($http,quizFactory){
        $http('somefile.json').success(function(data){
           quizFactory.questions=data;  
        }
     })
```

Here note that you have to dependency inject the **factory**, and yes, it is not necessary to manually parse the data, Angular will automatically look after it.