# Load json data into the factory file

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, factory

I am new to AngularJS and just started learning it. How can I load the JSON file into the script.js file without directly adding the entire data.
Here is the code of the program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="quizApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>QuizApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">QuizApp</h1>
    <quiz/>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/W6QWwoaqSvreW9bT3cH0?p=preview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to correct the json pasted in `ques.json` (by using quotes `""`) otherwise if you will invoke `$http.get()` then you will get exception due to invalid json.

Once you will correct the json content in `ques.json` then just use `$http` and assign the result to questions variable.

E.g.

```
app.factory('quizFactory', function($http) {

    var questions = [];

   $http.get('ques.json').success(function(data) {
     questions = data;
   })


    return {
        getQuestion: function(id) {
            if(id < questions.length) {
                return questions[id];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tLQwBwUr9MA4P8bF4b0q?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

```
 $http.get('ques.json')
       .then(function(result){
          $scope.questions = result.data;                
        });
```

Comment: how can i make this equal to the variable questions ?