# Using JSON data retrieved with AJAX outside success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem with storing JSON that I get with AJAX, to an outside variable for further usage. Ive checked this answer ([load json into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177548/load-json-into-variable)) which is really basic, but I'm doing wrong something else. My code is below.

```
function showZone() {
var data=null;
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/gui/templates/tracking/show_zones.php',
            //data: 'userid='+ uid ,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                data=json;
                $( '#res1' ).html( data[0].swlat );  

            }
 }); 
 return data;

}

function showZones() {
    var data=showZone();
    $( '#res2' ).html( data[0].swlat );  
}
```

For clearer picture of my problem I have two divs (#res1 & #res2), where I print the data. In #res1 I get the result as wanted, but #res2 doesnt print anything and I get an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null'. So the data is returned before ajax stores it in a variable. Is this the problem, or should I be storing json to a variable differently?
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Use callback simple.

Comment: loaded data stored in success function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**callback()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript). Consider following snippet:

```
function showZone() {
    var data = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/gui/templates/tracking/show_zones.php',
        //data: 'userid='+ uid ,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(json) {
            data = json;
            showZones(data);//callback

        }
    });
    //return data; No need to return data when we have async ajax

}
showZone(); // call when you want to make ajax call
function showZones(data) { // This function will call after ajax response
    $('#res2').html(data[0].swlat);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> > $.ajax returns immediately `return data` which is executed before the function you passed as success callback was even called.So its return as undefined .Its means you can't return ajax data .

For more example [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

But why can't you use simply like

```
  success: function(json) {
            data=json;
            $( '#res1' ).html( data[0].swlat );  
            $( '#res2' ).html( data[0].swlat ); 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for that link, I was thinking the problem is something like this yeah. I don't really need to show data in div, this was just for demonstration of my problem, I only wanted to use JSON data outside ajax function. However I'll solve this with a callback.