# Javascript variable affectation

Tags: javascript

Here is the deal: I am trying to read a file in JS and to affect its content to a variable I can manipulate outside the parsing function. In other words:

```
var content = "";
$.getJSON(dataPath, function(obj) {
    content = obj;
    console.log(content) //first log
 });
 console.log(content) // second log
```

I don't understand why the first log show the right `content` (JSon from a file), whereas the second says `content` is undefined.

What am I missing ?

Comment: `What am I missing?` understanding of promises and how they work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the pointer (can't fix the problem yet, but a least I know where to search !)

Comment: A very quick fix:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177548/load-json-into-variable

Which post stands:

    var jsonContent = (function () {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false, // Synchronize !
            'global': false,
            'url': dataPath,
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();